On the vertical positioning of the subscript for the restriction symbol
Based on this original answer of @egreg, and this answer proposed to a previous question I asked some time ago, currently I have my command for restriction of function defined as below:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \restrict { s m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \smash
        {
          \left.
            \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
            #2
            \mathchoice
              { \vphantom { \big| } }  % \displaystyle
              { \vphantom { \big| } }  % \textstyle
              { }                      % \scriptstyle
              { }                      % \scriptscriptstyle
          \right|
        }
      \IfBooleanT { #1 } { \mathclose { \vphantom { #2 } } }
      \sb { #3 }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

(The \smash is added so that a single superscript or subscript in the function being restricted would not result in the changing of size for the restriction bar.)
At the time this version appeared to have solved the issue proposed in my earlier question on the subscripts being too low.
However, recently I discovered that this still not work universally, as shown by the following picture:

Is there some way to improve this command so that the subscripts would appear in a more uniformed way?

Below is a MWE.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% \usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \restrict { s m m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \smash
        {
          \left.
            \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
            #2
            \mathchoice
              { \vphantom { \big| } }  % \displaystyle
              { \vphantom { \big| } }  % \textstyle
              { }                      % \scriptstyle
              { }                      % \scriptscriptstyle
          \right|
        }
      \IfBooleanT { #1 } { \mathclose { \vphantom { #2 } } }
      \sb { #3 }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

% seems fine, or maybe a bit too high?
\[
    \restrict{f}{U}=\frac{\restrict{g}{U}}{\restrict{h}{U}}
\]

% too low
\[
    \restrict*{\frac{\partial}{\partial X_i}}{P}
\]

% too low
\[
    \restrict*{\left(
        \begin{aligned}
            X &\to Y \\
            x &\mapsto y
        \end{aligned}
        \right)}{V}
\]

% for comparason
\[
    f |_V
\]

% for comparason
\[
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
        f
    \right|_V
\]

% for comparason
\[
    \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
        \left(
        \begin{aligned}
            X &\to Y \\
            x &\mapsto y
        \end{aligned}
        \right)
    \right|_V
\]

% % for comparason
% \[
%     \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
%         \left(
%         \begin{aligned}
%             X &\to Y \\
%             x &\mapsto y
%         \end{aligned}
%         \right)
%     \right|
%     \mathclose { \vphantom {
%         \begin{aligned}
%             X &\to Y \\
%             x &\mapsto y
%         \end{aligned}
%     } }
%     _V
% \]

\end{document}

